# Web page beacon

Tags: web-bluetooth

I would like to send a BLE Eddystone beacon from a web page. My application requires to send SSID info to a BLE listener. My thought is to have a user load a URL on a smartphone that would run JS to send periodic BLE Eddystone-UID beacons with SSID info embedded. I need the web page to work on both Android and iOS phones. Is there a simple way to do this using Javascript?

I looked into physical web but it did not seem to provide this capability.

thanks,
Ian

Answer (score 1):

The current version of the Web Bluetooth API specification allows websites, **running in the Central role**, to connect to remote GATT Servers over a BLE connection. What you're looking for is a way to run in the Server role to advertise your data.

In your case, I'd recommend you have a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/@abandonware/bleno